# Caret disappearing from TextBox because of Viewbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

When I change the resolution of my WPF the caret simply starts to disappear.

This occurs at lower resolutions like 1024x768.

Example:

Caret showing:

[image]

Caret disappears:

[image]

Caret returns:

[image]

```
<Viewbox>
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextFieldTextBox}" Margin="1590,795,65,200" />
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Is there any way today how to fix this?

Comment: Why are such large values are used for the `Margin`? The problem may be related to the resolution. Therefore, look at the following post: [Resolution independent or monitor size independent WPF apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4897849/6630084).

Comment: Margin has this value because I'm using 2k resolution for testing. the ViewBox works well for what I want, the only problem is Caret

Comment: Because of this 'TextBox' uses the **MaterialDesign** style try to remove `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextFieldTextBox}"` and check if it will work without it.

Comment: even after removing material design problem still remains

Comment: So, this is not related to the MaterialDesign. More like focus issue, but don't clear how it related to the screen resolution. You can check this with suggestion from **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14200909/6630084)** - use timer to set focus on the textbox,  to check it is related to focus or not.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a focus problem, the TextBox is focused correctly, even if the caret is not shown I can type normally, I found something that talks about the subject https://stackoverflow.com/a/40040881/12865533 I thought that after so long this problem had been fixed in newer versions